# PHP - How to calculate one month or one year later

Tags: php, date, recurly

I'd like to calculate next billing date of Recurly plan in PHP.
There are 2 types of billing cycle: yearly | monthly.
I tried to use DateTime and DateInterval classes, but didn't get expected results.

```
<?php
$referenceTime = new \DateTime('2016-01-31');
$oneMonthLater = $referenceTime->modify('+1 month');
var_dump($oneMonthLater);
// public 'date' => string '2016-03-02 00:00:00.000000'
```

Adding one month to the 31st of Januray gives me the second of March and not the 29th (or 28th) of February as I would expect.

The same for the 31st of August:

```
<?php
$referenceTime = new \DateTime('2016-08-31');
$oneMonthLater = $referenceTime->modify('+1 month');
var_dump($oneMonthLater);
// public 'date' => string '2016-10-01 00:00:00.000000'
```

If yearly, I expect Feb 29, 2016 + 1 year => Feb 28, 2017

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far... It will be easier for us to answer.

Comment: $next_bill_date = new DateTime();

        if ($plan_interval_unit == 'year') {
            $interval_spec = 'P'.$plan['plan_interval_length'].'Y';
        } else if ($plan_interval_unit == 'month') {
            $interval_spec = 'P'.$plan['plan_interval_length'].'M';
        }

        $next_bill_date->add(new DateInterval($interval_spec));

Comment: Add it in your question please. Hard to read/understand here... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_next_billing_date($now, $type, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $date = new DateTime($now);

    $y = $date->format("Y");
    $m = $date->format("m");
    $d = $date->format("d");

    if ($type == 'year') {
        $y++;
        if ($m == 2 && $d == 29) {
            $d = 28;
        }
    } else if ($type == 'month') {
        if ($m == 12) {
            $y++;
            $m = 1;
        } else {
            $m++;
        }

        $first_date = sprintf("%04d-%02d-01", $y, $m);
        $last_day_of_next_month = date('t', strtotime($first_date));

        if ($d > $last_day_of_next_month) {
            $d = $last_day_of_next_month;
        }
    } else {
        // not supported
        return false;
    }

    $date->setDate($y, $m, $d);

    return $date->format($format);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, if  `date > 28` `use` `last day of next month` else use `+1 month`

```
$get_date = strtotime("31-01-2016");
$dt = explode("-",$get_date);
$dt = $dt[0];
var_dump(($dt > 28) ? date("d-m-Y", strtotime("31-01-2016 last day of next month")) : date("d-m-Y", strtotime("31-01-2016 +1 month")));
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/691856)**

Answer (score 1):

You can call `modify` with PHP's `DateTime` object to calculate the next date relative to the current date. The following code shows how you would do it with your specific situation.

```
$next_bill_date = new DateTime();
switch($plan_interval_unit) {
    case "year":
        $next_bill_date->modify("last day of next month");
        break;

    case "month":
        $next_bill_date->modify("last day of this month next year");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like that:

```
if (date('d') !== date('d', strtotime('+1 month'))
    date ('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('last day of next month'));

if (date('d') !== date('d', strtotime('+1 year'))
    date ('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('last day of this month next year'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP inbuilt [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

```
// One month from today
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month'));

// One month from a specific date
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime('2016-12-06')));
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem specified though unless I'm missing something? If I use the date `2016-01-31` the result is actually `Wed, 02 Mar 2016...` but the OP was looking for it to return _"29th (or 28th) of February_".

Comment: You need past month OR future month ?!

Comment: I answered myself. Thank you for your help!